# F# TypeProvider "XMLProvider" gives System.Exception

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm trying to process Twitter tweets using the XML type provider as represented by the code below.  The code works fine when accessing tweet data values using LINQ XElement functions, however it fails with an exception saying: “XML mismatch: Expected exactly one 'title' child”, when using the type created by the XMLProvider.  I know namespaces are not given, however, I don't know how they would be specified with the provider, if they're needed.

```
// ...

open FSharp.Net
open FSharp.Data

let ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"

// General helpers for XML

let xelem s (el: XContainer) = el.Element(XName.Get(s, ns)) 
// ...
let xvalue (el: XElement) = el.Value

let twitterUri = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Windows8&rpp=100&lang=en"
type Tweets = XmlProvider<"SampleTweets.xml", Global=false>

let feed = Tweets.Load twitterUri

// title 0 & 1 produce correct values

let title0 = feed.XElement |> xelem "title" |> xvalue
let title1 = feed.XElement |> xelem "entry" |> xelem "title" |> xvalue

// title 2 produces: "XML mismatch: Expected exactly one 'title' child"

let title2 = feed.Title
let title3 = feed.GetEntries().[0].Title
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that the sample XML doesn't match the actual XML? Could you include both of the XML files here? (Or, even better, simplified versions of them that still show the issue.)

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug in FSharp.Data related to the fact that there's a default namespace in the xml `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`.

Version 1.1.3 fixed this, but you could also do the following as a workaround:

```
[<Literal>]
let twitterUri = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Windows8&rpp=100&lang=en"
type Tweets = XmlProvider<twitterUri>

let feedXml = (Http.Request twitterUri).Replace("xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"", null)

let feed = Tweets.Parse feedXml
let t = feed.Title
```

Comment: Gustavo has definitely emphasized that the XmlProvider is seriously flawed.  The Twitter feed xml should prove to be a formidable test case for that provider. For example, considering some elements qualified by `twitter:`:
    
`<feed ... >
    ...
    <entry>
        <twitter:metadata>
        <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
        </twitter:metadata>`
    
The provider definitely creates fields in the type for those 'twitter' qualified elements. 

    `let rt = feed.GetEntries().[0].Metadata.ResultType` 

However, the value of `ResultType` is inaccessible.

Comment: I don't think I said the provider was seriously flawed, I just said it had a bug. Anyway, I've submitted a pull request, it was an easy fix (https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/pull/114). The Xml is much less used than the other providers in FSharp.Data, as these days almost everything is Json, so it's natural it has more bugs.