# Debugging runtime of XmlProvider

Tags: f#, f#-data

I attached a the XmlProvider to what seems to be a valid xml (displays in IE, is validated by W3C tool)

When I write the program, everything type checks and I can compile.
However at runtime I have the following error:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

When I access

```
  let posts = (TyPosts.Parse lastposts).GetEntries()
```

Where entry is a node name.

=> where should I place a breakpoint ?

I can only managed to break on the TP construction, not on its actual data access !

To reproduce the initial pb, here is a script. the only modif should be the 2 first dlls.

```
#r @"Z:\clones\FSharp.Data\bin\v40\FSharp.Data.dll"
#r @"Z:\clones\FSharp.Data\bin\v40\FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Net.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open System
open System.Net
open FSharp.Data
open System.IO;
open System.Text;
open System.Xml;
[<Literal>] 
let lastposts = "lastposts.xml" 
let phase0 () =
  let fetch (url : string, auth) =
   use client = new WebClient()
   client.Headers.Add("user-agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US")
   client.DownloadString url
  let write(filename, content:string) = 
     use f= new StreamWriter(filename, false)
     f.Write(content)
  let posts () = fetch(@"http://squarism.com/feed/atom/", false)
  write(  __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__   + "/"+ lastposts, posts())
phase0()

[<Literal>]
let res = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
type TyPosts = XmlProvider<lastposts,ResolutionFolder=res> 
let posts = (TyPosts.Parse lastposts).GetEntries() // <-- TCHETCHENIA HERE !!
```

Comment: You shouldn't reference FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll, only FSharp.Data.dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of FSharp.Data are you using? I just tried this with 1.1.4 and it worked fine:

```
let feed = XmlProvider<"http://squarism.com/feed/atom/">.GetSample()
let entries = feed.GetEntries()
```

There was a problem with Xml namespaces that was recently fixed (see [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753005/f-typeprovider-xmlprovider-gives-system-exception))

In any case, the place to put the breakpoint is [here](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/XmlProvider/XmlRuntime.fs#L51) (in the `FSharp.Data.dll` assembly, not `FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll` assembly)

If 1.1.4 doesn't work please submit an issue on GitHub

Comment: That's indeed where I though I'd be called. I'll try it again. you actually ran it, not just compiled it ?

Comment: thank you for the confirmation anyway, I'll dig better with that confirmation.

Comment: Yes, I ran it both in FSI and as a console application